# How can I read multiple text files and store them in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, file, text

I have hit a mental wall. Basically, this code is supposed to execute and gather all the text files I have in a folder (and eventually update the text box every 10 seconds.) 
At the moment, it will only pull text from one or two files at once and that will be it. It will not update this textbox3 either. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to why this is happening?

Since I've been working with this code for hours I don't know how clear I am being. If you have any questions about it please feel free to ask. Thanks for looking.

```
public void read()
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"U:\My Documents\chat\", "*.txt",
                                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string file in filePaths)
    {
        TextReader objstream = new StreamReader(file);

        textBox3.Text = objstream.ReadToEnd();

        objstream.Close();

        textBox3.Select(textBox3.Text.Length, 0);
        textBox3.ScrollToCaret(); 

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `+=` instead of `=` to append the next stream. At the moment, you're overwriting the previous stream, regardless of where the caret is.

Comment: when you say it is not updating textbox3 what is the behaviour? Does it not show any data, does it show the data from the first file only or does it show the data from the final file only? I would imagine it would the be the latter option as it appears you are overwriting the textbox content each time.

Comment: You should use `using` ... `using (TextReader objStream = new StreamReader(file)) { ... }`, then you can omit the `Close()` call (the finally in a using will destruct the object, which will Close()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
textBox3.Text = objstream.ReadToEnd();
```

try

```
textBox3.Text += objstream.ReadToEnd();
```

edit 1: if you want to refresh this textbox, don't forget to clear its text before refreshing. (`textBox3.Text = ""` will do). you can put this line at the beginning of the `read()` as well.

edit 2: remove `break;` line in the for...each loop.

Comment: Thanks Emir Akaydın for the input however it's still not reading all the files into my textbox :S

Comment: Basically (probably going to laugh). I am writing a little addin for a healthcare service program which allows me to basically have a little forum chat in my c# program. Because Im not sure about using sockets due to firewalls; I am using Text files. So everyone using this program will create a little text file and be able to type into their indivdual text file and then the program pulls all the text files information together into their one text box. Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, it's not the proper way and you already know that. But as long as it solves your problems, you can use that method knowing it's not a real solution but a dirty workaround. i just noticed that break; btw. Remove that break; line in the for each loop. That's probably your problem.

Comment: Yeah it was in the end. Just noticed it myself and it works now. Except I have a new problem where it's not sorting the messages by the time I have given to them; which is fair enough. Just trying to fix that now. Not sure how to tell the program to sort the dates from the text files into order in the textbox3. Grr.

Comment: Instead of directly inserting the text to TextBox, you should insert all the message lines (seperated) to a collection/dictionary or any other suitable sortable list using the dates as keys. After sorting the items, you should generate the complete output. You need to read some documentation on collections or dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really need to meddle with the stream so much, I'd just use the method on the System.IO.File static class to read and return all the text. Using that and AppendText you can basically combine it into one statement. I would recommend however putting some Exception checking in there on the file reading.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"U:\My Documents\chat\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);  
foreach (string file in filePaths)
  textBox3.AppendText(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file));
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also try

```
textBox3.AppendText(objstream.ReadToEnd());
```

One thing to keep in mind here though is file encoding. If the file encoding is not UTF-8 it may display differently in the textbox vs a text editor.

Hope this Helps

Comment: Basically (probably going to laugh). I am writing a little addin for a healthcare service program which allows me to basically have a little forum chat in my c# program. Because Im not sure about using sockets due to firewalls; I am using Text files. So everyone using this program will create a little text file and be able to type into their indivdual text file and then the program pulls all the text files information together into their one text box. Does this make sense?